# Magento 2 - Direct download external file

Tags: magento2, ajax, download

In Magento 2, I try to force download a pdf file from an external link (I don't have the source file).

All I succeed is opening the file in the new browser tab but the direct download doesn't work.

Do you have any solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the download link in `<a>` tag, you can add download inside tag:

```
<a href="your-file-url.pdf" download>
  Download file
</a>
```

Hope this help